# VB.NET set a password length to save in database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to make the password entered by the user must be more than 8?
This is my code but it didn't work

I tried to register with a password less than 8 and it was saved

```
If PasswordTextBox.Text >= 8 Then
                Try
                    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Database2.accdb")
                    Dim insert As String = "Insert into Table1 values('" & NameTextBox.Text & "','" & Staff_IDTextBox.Text & "','" & Phone_NoTextBox.Text & "','" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "','" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "');"
                    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Saved")
                    Me.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error")
                End Try
            Else
                MsgBox("Password must be more than 8 character")
            End If
```

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary vulnerable to sql injection!

Comment: Also, don't save raw passwords! You must give them a salt and then use a cryptographic hash. This is too important to even do wrong in learning or proof of concept code.

Comment: Finally, if an exception is thrown, the `Me.Close()` line might never run, and `conn.Close()` is never called. You should wrap the connection in a `Using` block or put the `Close()` calls in a `Finally` block.

Comment: Thank you for your viewpoints. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the length. Something like

```
If PasswordTextBox.Text.Length >= 8 Then
```